# Access 2010 - Parent and child forms share the same table

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a budget database, and while planning out the tables went fine, forms are proving to be trickier.

I have a 'transactions' table, and two queries based off it. The tables and column names are below

- 'people_to_reimburse' : payee_name, total
- 'unwritten_checks' : payee_name, amount, description, date_incurred

I'd like to make a form where you can go through the people to reimburse, and there's a subform showing which checks are theirs. Obviously, the payee_name would be the field to link on.

However, in Access's Form Wizard, when I select these two tables, I get an error of:

> You have chosen fields from record sources which the wizard can't connect. You may have chosen fields from a table and from a query based on that table.

How would I set up a form like this, if it's possible? If not, why can't I?